# Differentiation problem, need some suggestions to solve it.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)$ a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^2-{(0,0)}$.
We say that $f$ is homogenous of degree 1 if $\forall t > 0$ and $\forall (x,y) \neq (0,0)$  it is verified

$$f(t(x,y)) = tf(x,y).$$

Show that $f$ is homogeneous of degree 1 if and only if

$$\bigtriangledown f(x,y)\cdot  (x,y)= f(x,y)\qquad \forall (x,y)\neq (0,0)$$

I could prove $\Leftarrow $ direction but I cant manage to prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction, can somebody suggest me an idea to solve the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use the chain rule.

$$\frac{d}{dt} (f \circ c)(t) = \nabla f(c(t)) \cdot c'(t)$$